# mssql_query(): Query failed

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a script, which makes a query to a remote database, now the problem is that sometimes it returns this error. Most of the time it is working, but still the error persists in like 5 out of 10 runs of the script. Data is always the same, query doesn't change too.

```
mssql_get_last_message();
```

Doesn't return anything.

Also I tried to increase the memory. The most interesting part is that it doesn't return the error every time.

The error comes in this part of the code:

```
    if ( ! $this->_result = mssql_query($query))
    {
        throw new Exception($this->get_error_message());
    }
```

Also
`set_time_limit(0); 
ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);`

Didn't helped either.

Comment: Could be a number of things. Maybe try increasing set_time_limit, or set to unlimited for troubleshooting `set_time_limit(0)` (remove it afterwards and set it to something sane).

Comment: No luck, but thanks!

Comment: Did you say no errors at all? What about PHP errors, or other logs perhaps? Even on the remote server might be timeout or whatever errors somewhere. It's a tricky one to suggest for here as it needs poking and prodding to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could have been a server issue. At the moment every query works and I get no errors.